# Docker Compose with RabbitMQ - Connection Refused when connecting from other service internally

Tags: c#, .net, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I am using **docker compose** with a **.net core service** and **RabbitMQ**. I try to connect to **rabbitMQ** from a different service. I've seen many questions but **none** of them worked or had an answer.

I know you should not use '**localhost**' to connect with another service but the name you gave in the **docker-compose** file.

I am really curious about the answer!

**What I tried**

1. Add depends on in the docker compose file
2. Add links in the docker compose file
3. Add restart: always in the docker compose file
4. Changed the connection link to : amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
5. Changed the connection link to : amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq/
6. Cleaned and rebuilt the solution many times
7. Changed the order in the docker compose file. RabbitMQ is now Nr.1, after that the other services.
8. Added container_name
9. Added hostname

Here is my docker compose file

```yaml
version: '3.0'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - "7100:15672"
      - "7101:5672"
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq:/rabbitmq
  dbPosts:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
        - 3307:3306
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
        MYSQL_DATABASE: postsdb
    volumes:
        - dbpostdata:/var/lib/mysql
  post-service:
    depends_on:
        - dbPosts
        - rabbitmq
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: post-service/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
  
volumes:
    dbpostdata:
    rabbitmq:
```

How the connection is made :

```cs
if (_connection == null)
{
   ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory()
      {
         Uri = new Uri("amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672"),
         AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true
      };
   _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
}
```

But when I try to run docker-compose up, I receive the following error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: No such device or address
```

Comment: To double-check: the code fragment you show is getting run as part of the `post-service`, and not from a development environment on your host?

Comment: The code with the connection is not from the post-service. It is a different "project", a class library called 'Shared'. I added a reference from post-service to the class library. In the post-service I have this piece of code in the start-up:             ```services.AddMessagePublishing("PostService");```. And from that it will make the connection I think

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I got the wrong package version...